# Matlab: How can I create a 3D Grid?

Tags: matlab

I want to write a function, which creates a 3D-grid with a ball inside of grid. It should be 3D. 
I found [this example](http://www.k-wave.org/documentation/example_ivp_3D_simulation.php#heading3) and it is exactly what I want, but I don't have any idea how I can add this in a function m-file.

This is my code:

```
function kgrid = makeGrid(Nx, dx, Ny, dy); 

% create the computational grid
Nx = 64;            % number of grid points in the x direction
Ny = 64;            % number of grid points in the y direction
Nz = 64;            % number of grid points in the z direction
dx = 0.1e-3;        % grid point spacing in the x direction [m]
dy = 0.1e-3;        % grid point spacing in the y direction [m]
dz = 0.1e-3;        % grid point spacing in the z direction [m]

kgrid = makeGrid(Nx, dx, Ny, dy, Nz, dz);

end
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [the example](http://www.k-wave.org/documentation/example_ivp_3D_simulation.php#heading3), it says on that website, that [`makeGrid`](http://www.k-wave.org/documentation/makeGrid.php) is a function. The function is part of a [3rd party, open source, Matlab toolbox](http://www.k-wave.org/).
If you have that toolbox (for the download apparently you need a login on the website), you should have the function `makeGrid`.

If you don't, you can try Matlab's function [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html):

```
xgv = linspace(0,1,64); % this will give you 64 points between 0 and 1
ygv = linspace(0,1,64);
zgv = linspace(0,1,64);
```

**OR**

```
xgv = 0:1e-4:1; % this will give you a spacing of 1e-4 between the gridpoints
ygv = 0:1e-4:1;
zgv = 0:1e-4:1;
```

and then use **either of the above** with `meshgrid`:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(xgv,ygv,zgv);
```